# Fedora Desktop Environment

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, kde

I am choosing Fedora because of its relation to Red Hat (I want my personal laptop to help prepare me for any future encounters with it). Gnome 3 is the default desktop environment for both, if I understand correctly, so I am thinking I need to use it given my intent. However, I think I like KDE better. Will choosing one over the other put me at an advantage/disadvantage if it ever comes to me needing to do/understand administrative tasks on Red Hat? I know I can switch back and forth, but I'd rather not get attached if it will become an issue.

I'm new, so I don't know what I don't know. I just want to make sure my own personal preference choice does not hinder me in the future. This is NOT a preference question, but a technical one, at least that's how I intend it.

Thanks in advance for your cordiality and assistance.

- Jeff

Comment: You will eventually have to learn how stuff fits together anyway. The server is usually the old crusty and rather unchanging 1970s like terminal environment, you will have to learn it if you want to do server related stuff.
The GUI world is a chaotic and confusing mess, unless you want to write GUI applications, the actual environment shouldn't matter too much though. However, there are also de-facto standard gui tools like "Network Manager" that merit further investigation.

Comment: @TNierath: RHEL provides `nmtui`, so even then a GUI isn't required.

Comment: @TNierath - Thank you. Are you saying that I should learn to use the command line well, and that if I do the environment won't matter much? So, the RHEL/Debian choice is more important than the desktop environment I choose? And by choosing Fedora I've done well?

Comment: The Desktop Environment won't matter much for running a server. I personally don't like Red Hat, but if you want to work with Red Hat Systems (cause $$$) in the future, then it's a valid choice of course.
And yeah, network manager has a tui, but for a pure server, I prefer the simpler static configuration tools.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - nmtui looks like the systems I used to use back in the day (and like BIOS). I'll feel right at home once I get the hang of it. :)

Comment: @TNierath - Cool, thank you. I am certainly looking to "maximize my value" ($$$), but mostly just want to be as proficient as possible in my new career. I'm back in school for Information Systems. My interest in Linux is primarily professional. I ran Ubuntu on an old desktop a couple of years ago for the heck of it. I'm finding that having access to Linux will make my life easier, and I just decided to dive in. I have a Surface Pro with Windows 10 on it if I freak out and need to run back to safety. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to learn how to use the command line tools available, and all Fedora DEs either provide or allow a terminal emulator.

Additionally, consider installing CentOS in a VM. CentOS is a rebuild of RHEL and therefore essentially provides identical tools, but is less suited as a casual desktop than Fedora.

Comment: Thank you. I've got two of Sobell's books, one on Fedora/RHEL and another on Commands and such. I've committed to working through both books, but to someone who doesn't know much about either one :(  So, I might be making a lot of work for myself. Good idea or no?

Comment: Having seen neither of those books I can't tell you anything about them.

Comment: They are big and fat and about Linux. Lol... :) No worries. FYI, It's these two:
https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Guide-Fedora-Enterprise-Linux/dp/0133477436
https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Guide-Commands-Editors-Programming/dp/0134774604/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=3M8QRZHQKP9Q2SS1NKPT